# How to export a single header file for multiple shared libraries?

Tags: cmake

I got a top-level CMakeLists like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6.2)

project(Template)

set(CMAKE_LINK_DEPENDS_NO_SHARED ON)

add_subdirectory(external/libA)
add_subdirectory(external/libB)
add_subdirectory(external/libC)

add_subdirectory(apps/app1)
add_subdirectory(apps/app2)
```

It's a simple project which has 3 shared libraries `{libA, libB, libC}` and a couple of executables `{app1, app2}` which use those libraries.

My question is next, I've seen CMake gives some helpers to avoid going through the hazzle of coding custom headers and messing up with .defs to export symbols with something like below:

```
include (GenerateExportHeader)
GENERATE_EXPORT_HEADER(libA
             BASE_NAME libA
             EXPORT_MACRO_NAME SHARED_EXPORT
             EXPORT_FILE_NAME shared_EXPORTS.h
             STATIC_DEFINE SHARED_EXPORTS_BUILT_AS_STATIC)
```

My question is, can I use the above snippet for all my shared libraries? If so, how and where should I place it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't parameter multiple libraries with only one call. You must use `GenerateExportHeader` for each of your shared libraries.

So you will have one call to `GENERATE_EXPORT_HEADER` for `libA`, one for `libB`, one for `libC`, each with their own parameters.